# Using fscanf without taking in the input from the file at the moment

Tags: c, file, scanf

Ok i wanna use fscanf without actually taking the input from the file at this point.

so i was thinking something like this

```
while ( ( fscanf(stdin)) !=EOF) {
 continue...

}
```

later in the program i will be using the information in another function i was just wondering if this is possible.

Comment: If you don't want to read input, then what do you want `fscanf` to do?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: `fscanf(stdin)` : This does not compile.

Comment: If you don't want what you read, what you are looking for is fseek

Comment: You can't fseek stdin or similar, though...

Comment: I was wrong about what i needed to do, i pretty much have to continue my loop until ctl-d is pressed so i am trying to figure thato ut now

Answer (score 1):

You can't rewind or peek stdin (you can ungetc, but it's only guaranteed to work for one char), so your best bet would be to malloc() or realloc() some memory on a line-by-line basis (or whatever works for you) and pop what you scan into some array until you're ready to use it.

Note that stdin is blocking I/O as well, so your program will stall waiting for input unless you do something between scans.